How to run substrate-parachain-template as parachain testnet?
everyone.
Could you please help me on deploying my substrate-parachain-template as testnet?
https://docs.substrate.io/test/set-up-a-test-network/
I am following this reference. But I receive this errors after running this command.
./zombienet-linux-x64 spawn config.toml -p native


the guide is outdated and probably the relaychain's nodes are crashing because of the missing workers. Can you copy the workers to the bin folder (the same directory where the polakadot binary is present) with this command
cp ./target/release/polkadot-*-worker ../bin

And try to run again the network with zombienet.
Thanks!
